# How to add another condition to SQL NOT IN in where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have some tables to maintain shoes.

```
Brand ( brand_id, brand_name )
Initial_order table ( brand_name, shoe_count )
Sales table ( shoe_id, brand_name, purchase_date, returned_Date)
```

Now in our system if return_date is null, we assume sales is complete.
Now query I am looking for is:
`Return brand names which are completely sold out`, ie no shoe should have ever been returned ( Sales.return_Date == NULL ) and all shoes have been sold.

Here is the logic

```
select brand_id
from   brand
where  brand_name NOT IN ( select brand_name
                     from Sales
                     where returned_Date IS NOT NULL)
```

This query returns me all the brands that have not been returned, But, an additional condition I need to verify is -> `Initial_order.shoe_count` = `count of brand entries in Sales table`

I am struggling to understand how to hook up this additional check in the previous query.

Comment: For future reference, some sample data from each table, and a minimal example, would greatly assist others in giving you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this all in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select b.brand_id
from brand b
where b.brand_name NOT IN (select s.brand_name
                           from Sales s
                           where s.returned_Date IS NOT NULL
                          ) and
      (select io.shoe_count
       from initial_order io
       where io.brand_name = b.brand_name
      ) = 
      (select count(*)
       from Sales s
       where s.brand_name = b.brand_name and s.returned_Date IS NULL
     )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your schema appears to have some problems, e.g. you are joining tables using the `brand_name` rather than an ID which could always be unique.  In any case, I think you can approach this by joining the `Brand` table to two subqueries.  The first subquery finds the number of brand entries in the `Initial_order` table, and the second subquery finds the number of entries which were not returned.  I assume, therefore, that a given brand which has matching counts therefore means all orders have been completed succesfully.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Brand t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT brand_name, SUM(shoe_count) AS shoe_count
    FROM Initial_order
    GROUP BY brand_name
) t2
    ON t1.brand_name = t2.brand_name
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        brand_name,
        SUM(CASE WHEN returned_Date IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS shoe_count_sales
    FROM Sales
    GROUP BY brand_name
) t3
    ON t1.brand_name = t3.brand_name
WHERE t2.shoe_count = t3.shoe_count_sales
```